# Merging rows if a word is repeated in a column in R

Tags: r, merge

The title it is weird since I don't know how to explain it exactly, so I'll show you the data set I have:

```
   NUTS_NAME                species
1     Lleida        Argynnis paphia
2     Lleida      Limenitis reducta
3     Girona           Pieris rapae
4     Girona       Pieris brassicae
5  Barcelona          Colias crocea
6  Tarragona        Argynnis paphia
7  Tarragona      Limenitis reducta
8  Tarragona          Colias crocea
9  Tarragona Anthocharis cardamines
```

And what I'm trying to do (if possible, I prefer having the species list in alphabetic order):

```
  NUTS_NAME                species
1 Barcelona          Colias crocea
2    Girona       Pieris brassicae, Pieris rapae
3    Lleida        Argynnis paphia, Limenitis reducta
4 Tarragona Anthocharis cardamines, Argynnis paphia, Colias crocea, Limenitis reducta
```

Thanks!

Comment: The example is clear. Perhaps the question title can be something like, "How to combine/aggregate row elements based on a grouping category in R?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(species ~ NUTS_NAME, unique(df1), toString)
```